# using azure CLI getting the number of instances in a cloud service

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-cli

I am trying to get all the information of a specific cloud service we are using through the azure-cli (xplat) however the one thing i cannot find is how to find the number of instances for a given service?

looking in the azure web interface (manage.windowsazure.com) there is a tab called instances however those machines don't appear when using 
azure service show or azure vm list

any direction would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This cli command should list all the instances you have.

```
az resource list --query "[?type=='Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'].name"
```